# MVC 3 Drop Down List Not Binding to Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my application I have a drop down list to represent different choices.  Note that `Paragraph` is a model and the section is just one field in the model.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Sections")
```

And here is my controller.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var paragraph = db.Paragraphs.Find(id);

    ViewBag.Sections = new SelectList(
        db.Sections.Select(s => new { s.ID, s.Name }),
        "ID", "Name", paragraph.SectionID
    );

    return View(paragraph);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Paragraph paragraph, HttpPostedFileBase document)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do some stuff.
    }

    ViewBag.Sections = new SelectList(
        db.Sections.Select(s => new { s.ID, s.Name }),
        "ID", "Name", paragraph.SectionID
    );

    return View(paragraph);
}
```

When I submit the form though the drop down list is not bound to the model.  Causing `ModelState.IsValid` to be false and making my life horrible.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: When I submit the form I get the following error:

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Sections'.
```

**EDIT**: It appears that I only get the preceding error when I try to submit the file.

**EDIT**: Model

```
public class Paragraph
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Major { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Minor { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
}
```

Form: (It's a lot.)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/Paragraph/Edit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="section">Section</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.DropDownList("Sections")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="major">Major</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="number" class="input-large" name="major" value="@Model.Major" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="minor">Minor</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="number" class="input-large" name="minor" value="@Model.Minor" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-large" name="name" value="@Model.Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="document">Document</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="file" class="input-file" name="document" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
            <a class="btn" href="/Paragraph/Show/@Model.ID">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is late, but better late than never.  When you use one of the helpers provided by `HtmlHelper` it generates the `input` name behind the scenes.  The generated format for this name is `Model.Field`.  For example, a paragraph with a field called "Name" would become `Paragraph.Name`.

The definition for `DropDownList` that accepts one parameter uses the name of the drop-down list as the name of the `input` though.  So, a call to `DropDownList("Sections")` would create an `input` with a name of "Sections."

In the end though, I decided to concede to Razor and use the built-in HTML helpers.  So my drop-down list code looks like: `DropDownListFor(vm => vm.Paragraph.SectionID, Models.Sections)`.

Comment: Using ViewModels and strongly typed helpers is generally the way to go. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering why you are not using strongly type helpers like Html.TextBoxFor etc? You can pass optional html attributes with them if required

I'd make your dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.SectionID,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.Sections)
```

Others

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model =>model.ID)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.Major)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.Minor)
```

File can be `<input type="file" class="input-file" name="document" />`

That should give you the model to bind to. You will be sure of getting the correct names etc back. Also I am including the ID as part of the form.

Comment: I updated my question (first paragraph) to reflect some details.  Basically, the drop down list is part of a model and it is not being bound to the model.

Comment: Could you you post the form of the view and the  paragraph model.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML code to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SectionID, ViewBag.Sections as SelectList)
```

If you don't have a model for this page, then use the code below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Sections", ViewBag.Sections as SelectList)
```

Comment: It's really weird.  It works for `GET` and on `POST` when I don't upload a file.  But when I supply a file it freaks out and errors.

Comment: Have you tried different files? Neither a file, or a property called document, are included in the model so not sure why the presence or absence of a file would affect validation of the Model State

Answer (score 0):

So weird! I used to use

```
@Html.DropDownList("permissionsID", String.Empty)
```

and it worked fine - all of a sudden, im receiving the same problem.
The ddl is not submitting its selected value on the Create (posted) controller method)

So i used

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.permissionID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.permissionsID)
```

and it worked fine!

However I have older controllers that still work till today using the old method - just its not liking it for my new controllers!

It really defies logic...

Comment: Welcome to the site - could you rephrase this so it reads more like an answer to the question at hand, rather than thinking aloud? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Friend had the same problem when doing cascading dropdownlist

And there is no why to bind parent dropdownlist. So what I did was to fill the parent dropdownlist the same way as the soon. Created an action, called it on json and filled it using jquery.

My action on controller:

```
public ActionResult GetStates()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            using (MyModel banco = new myModel())
            {

                return Json(new SelectList(banco.SyStates.ToList(), "StateId", "StateName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
        }
        return View();

    }
```

The view:

```
      <select id="StateList" name="StateList"></select> 

<script>

   $(document).ready(function () {



         var URL = "/ControllerName/GetStates";
         $.getJSON(URL, function (data) {



         var items = '<option>Selecione o estado</option>';
         $.each(data, function (i, State) {
             items += "<option value='" + State.Value + "'>" + State.Text + "</option>";
             // state.Value cannot contain ' character. We are OK because state.Value = cnt++;

         });
         $('#StateList').html(items);
         //$('#CitiesTrID').show();

     })

 });
```

Got cascading example on:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx